# How to Create a create_dialog() Method in Android Studio in which you can pass the name of the Dialog Name you want to create with the Method

Tags: java, android-studio, oop

i want to create a Method which creates a dialog in Android Studio, but i also want to pass in the name of the Dialog which should be used as the Dialogname.
Until now i use the following metgod to create Dialogs:

```
    Dialog DialogName = new Dialog(context);
    //Parameters of the Dialog
    //Parameters of the Dialog
    //Parameters of the Dialog
    //Parameters of the Dialog
    //Parameters of the Dialog
    DialogName.show();
```

But since the parameteres are the same everytime but the names of the dialoges change i just want to use a method to handle rest for me something like

```
    create_dialog_method("my_new_Dialog",MainActivity.this);
    //Some Other Code
    my_new_Dialog.dismiss();
```

The method i want to declare outside of onCreate Method but within AppCompat would be something like:

```
    private void create_dialog_method(String DialogName,Context context) {
    Dialog DialogName = new Dialog (context);
    //Other parameters which are the same for every dialog
    //Other parameters which are the same for every dialog
    //Other parameters which are the same for every dialog
    //Other parameters which are the same for every dialog
    //Other parameters which are the same for every dialog
    DialogName.show();
}
```

Thanks in Regards for any help

Comment: Could you redraft to clarity the question? Shouldn't the dialog appear on the Andoid device or emulator? And that can have a title, but isn't that different than the name this local variable of type Dialog you've declared?

Comment: Yes youre right i could use a string as the parameter of the dialog to give the method the title too but title is not neccessary when creating dialogs. I just dont want to retype other parameters like dialoglayout,dialogbackground and so on.

Comment: If you need to keep a reference to the object, the factory method's return type should not be ``void``. It should be a Dialog. By the way, the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs say to avoid instantiating Dialog directly - instead subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach to create custom dialogs is to create a new class named 'mycustomdialog' whşch extends the normal 'Dialog' Class from AppCompat in order to have same functionality. Then for parameters like width, length..... And all the parameters which should stay fixed for each dialog, I would set these properties within the 'mycustomdialog' Class and add a String parameter to the constructor of rhe class to set the different names.